# Can you copy a highlighted text onto clipboard with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was just wondering if it's possible to highlight a text and copy it to clipboard by right clicking and selecting my extension from the ContextMenu (I know, I could just click copy but the function would just be one part of the extension I plan to make). I tried document.execcommmand('copy') but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: _"I was just wondering if it's possible to highlight a text and copy it to clipboard by right clicking and selecting my extension from the ContextMenu"_ Can you include `javascript` which implements custom entry at contextmenu at Question?

Comment: Misread your question before.  I do not have a direct solution.  I have worked with extensions some and it is possible for them to access the DOM of the page you are on.  As far as the specific javascript to copy a highlighted text.  I am not entirely sure of.

Comment: Other than that answer "Yes". What are you expecting to get out of this question?

Answer (score 0):

This can only happen with content script. It the script which plays with the web page DOM.